# Getting the part of a string after the occurrence of last backslash

Tags: php, string, explode, strstr

How to get all letters without the last part of string, for example:

```
$string = 'namespace\name\driver\some\model';
```

The expected output is:

```
namespace\name\driver\some\
```

Comment: Explaining how you define "last part" would help.

Comment: What up with the diarrhea at the beginning of the post?

Comment: What language are you using? Depending on the language there could be some in-built features that could help you.

Comment: sorry guyz but i try to send a post and is problem with tittle. Always  my tittle not have standards ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to you take a substring, no need to mess with explodes/implodes/array...

Try this basic thing:

```
$string = substr($string, 0, strrpos($string, '\\') + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) to split the string by `\` and then [`implode()`](http://php.net/explode) to join the new string:

```
echo implode('\\', array_slice(explode('\\', $string), 0, -1));
```

Or use a regular expression to replace everything after the last slash:

```
echo preg_replace('#[^\\\\]*$#', '', $string);
```

Output:

```
namespace\name\driver\some
```

Answer (score 1):

assuming you are using php,

use this,

```
<?php
$string ='namespace\name\driver\some\model';
$output= implode('\\', array_slice(explode('\\', $string), 0, -1));
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you try using a regular expression? '.*\\'

Answer (score 1):

Find postion of slash frm the right - you have to escape it with additional \

```
<?php
$string = "namespace\name\driver\some\model";
$lastslash = strrpos($string,"\\") + 1;
$new_string = substr($string,0,$lastslash);
echo "new string - ".$new_string." ".$lastslash;    
?>
```